# Como concatenar multiplas Strings em Python?

Tags: python, string, concatenação-de-string

O seguinte método `c.filtraNome(nome)` efetua uma consulta no banco (*sqlite3*), entretanto, não sei como posso agrupar cada campo e retornar a consulta já formatada da seguinte maneira:

```
Nome:  Fulano Silvia
Idade:  19
CPF:  00000000000
Email:  fulano@email.com.br
Celular:  1131345678
Cidade:  Nova Vila
UF:  MT
Data do Cadastro:  2015-08-25
```

Tentei concatenar as strings com o operador `+` e com o método `''.join('String')` mas não obtive sucesso em nenhum deles.

Rotina que efetua a consulta:

```
def filtraNome(self,nome):
        self.db.cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome like ? ; """,(['%' + nome + '%']))
        for campo in self.db.cursor.fetchall():
            self.dados = 'Nome: '.join(campo[1]).join('Idade: '.join(campo[2])).join('CPF: '.join(campo[3])).join('Email: '.join(campo[4])).join('Celular: '.join(campo[5])).join('Cidade: '.join(campo[6])).join('UF: '.join(campo[7])).join('Data do cadastro: '.join(campo[8])) #Gera um erro nesta linha.

        return self.dados
```

O erro que esta sendo gerado ao usar o método `join()`:

```
self.dados = 'Nome: '.join(campo[1]).join('Idade: '.join(campo[2])).join('CPF: '.join(campo[3])).join('Email: '.join(campo[4])).join('Celular: '.join(campo[5])).join('Cidade: '.join(campo[6])).join('UF: '.join(campo[7])).join('Data do cadastro: '.join(campo[8]))
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Rotina que chama o método da classe `ClienteDB`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = ClienteDB()
    if c.cria_tabela():
        print("Tabela %s criada com sucesso.", c.tb_nome)
    #c.inserir_registro()
    #c.listar_todos()
    nome = raw_input("Informe um nome para pesquisa: ")
    print(c.filtraNome(nome))
```

Como eu posso concatenar os campos retornados da consulta no *Python*?

Comment: qual erro é gerado na linha ?

Comment: Este erro: **TypeError: can only join an iterable**

Comment: o join só funciona com arrays ou "coisas que podem ser iteradas"... com o '+' dá algum erro ?

Comment: Sim com mais tambem retorna um erro, no ultimo registro `"Data: " + campo[8]`, os dois estão retornando erro.

Comment: provavelmente tá dando um "index out of range"... estou vendo que você começou a pegar os campos do array a partir do indice 1... mas o array começa em 0.. ta certo isso ?

Comment: O índice zero e o **id** eu não exibo ele.

Comment: qual o erro que está dando entao ? Faça o seguinte... para evitarmos uma "conversa" nos comentários, edite sua pergunta colocando mais detalhes, mostrando quais as abordagens que você usou e quais foram os erros quando usou elas.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, tenta concatenar usando `Nome: + str(campo[1])...` e me avisa do resultado pra eu postar como resposta. Eu realmente acho que esse é o problema.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tu deves converter os teus itens dentro de `campo[indice]` para `string` antes de tentar concatená-los.

Um exemplo simples e que resolveria o problema (embora não seja recomendado), é usar:

```
'Nome: ' + str(campo[1])
```

No entanto, `Python` tem várias formas para formatação de `strings`. Você pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui](http://turing.com.br/pydoc/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html), [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) e [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

## Alguns exemplos de formatação de `strings`

Você pode usar o método `str.format()` para solucionar seu problema, porque ele converte automaticamente para `string` os dados que são passados para ele.
Um método básico de uso, seria:

```
'Nome: {} Idade: {} CPF: {}'.format(campo[1], campo[2], campo[3])
```

As chaves são substituídos pelos objetos passados para o método `str.format()`, respeitando a ordem dos parâmetros.

Quando se tem muitos campos para concatenar, pode ser interessante "numerar" estes parâmetros, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
'Nome: {0} Idade: {1} CPF: {2}'.format(campo[1], campo[2], campo[3])
```

Aqui `{0}` será substituído pelo primeiro parâmetro do método e assim sucessivamente (lembrando que você não precisa colocar os `campos de formatação` em ordem.

Outra forma interessante de usar este método, principalmente quando se tem muitos campos para formatar, é usar os parâmetros com `nomes` ao invés de `números`, como por exemplo:

```
'Nome: {nome} Idade: {idade} CPF: {cpf}'.format(nome = campo[1], idade = campo[2], cpf = campo[3])
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, desta maneira funcionou, consegui separar  os valores e agrupa-los.

Answer (score 7):

Python tem há muito tempo vários esquemas de formatar strings, com interpolação de dados, de forma que dão ao usuário bastante controle e separação do que é dado e do que é código.

Isso é certametne o que você quer fazer - melhor que concatenar: ter uma strign grande, com o layout geral de como você quer sua saída, e interpolar os dados lidos do banco de dados.

Atualmente (Python 2.7. 3.4) a forma mais recomendada de se fazer isso é com o método `format` das strings. VOcê pode até usar uma string de multiplas linhas - as delimitadas por aspas triplas (`"""`) para criar seu layout, deixando os slots para serme preenchidos pelos campos com os marcadores `{ }`. Como é uma strign longa, o melhor é usar a opção que deixa você dar nome ao compo que vai em cada marcados (`{campo}`).

No seu caso, isso pode ser algo do tipo:

```
self.dados = """\
Nome:  {nome}
Idade:  {idade} 
CPF: {cpf}
Email:  {email}
Celular:  {celular}
Cidade:  {cidade}
UF:  {uf}
Data do Cadastro:  {data}""".format(nome=campo[1],idade=campo[2],...,uf=campo[...])
```

O `.format` converte automáticamente os dados para sua representação como string - se vocẽ não desejar isso (por exeplo, quiser formatar um campo com números decimais com um número específico de casas), o método tem uma minilinguagem de formatação, - deixando você especificar o tipo, e números de casas decimais após colocar `:` depois do nome do campo. Ex. : `{total:06.2f}` diria que o "total" seria um campo numérico com 6 digitos, preenchidos a esquerda com "0 e duas casa após o ponto decimal. O venerável Luciano Ramalho cirou um cartão de cola para o Format que está online aqui:
http://python.pro.br/material/cartao-format.pdf  -  A docuemtnação oficial está aqui: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Ah, se você verificar a documentação do conector do banco de dados, vai ver que existe um "dictcursor" que traz as colunas do seu select como um dicionário, em vez de ordenadas em sequência. Se você mudar seu código para usar dict cursor, poderá chamar o format direto com a linha do cursor da query, algo como `"""...""".format(**campos)`

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!