# Problema ao utilizar if elif else (erro no else)

Tags: python, algoritmo, python-3.x

```
n = input ("informe seu nome ")
b1 = float(input("informe sua nota em Biologia no 1º Bimestre "))
b2 = float(input("informe sua nota em Biologia no 2º Bimestre "))
b3 = float(input("informe sua nota em Biologia no 3º Bimestre "))
b4 = float(input("informe sua nota em Biologia no 4º Bimestre "))
media = (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4
if media >= 6:
   print (n,", sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você foi aprovado")
elif media <= 5.9 and media >= 4: 
   print (n,",sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você esta de recuperação")
else media < 3.9: # Não tô entendendo este erro
print (n,", sua média em Biologia foi",media,"Você esta reprovado")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não se utiliza condição no `else` porque o `else` se torna valido quando as outras condições não são verdadeiras.

Veja abaixo:

```
if media >= 6:
    print ("{nome} sua média em Biologia é {media} você foi aprovado".format(nome=n, media=media))
elif media <= 5.9 and media >= 4: 
    print ("{nome} sua média em Biologia é {media}, você esta de recuperação".format(nome=n, media=media))
else: # Não se utiliza condição no else.
    print ("{nome} sua média em Biologia foi {media}. Você esta reprovado".format(nome=n, media=media))
```

Veja mias sobre como usar comandos condicionais em python [aqui](https://powerpython.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/aula-python-if-else/).

Você também pode utilizar o `format` para formata a exibição de suas strings, veja mais aqui nesta resposta sobre [concatenação de strings em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82733/como-concatenar-multiplas-strings-em-python).

Answer (score 2):

O "else" não recebe parâmetros, é uma condição aplicável apenas quando as outras falham, logo:

```
else media < 3.9: # Não tô entendendo este erro
```

Deveria passar para:

```
elif media < 3.9: # Não tô entendendo este erro
```

No entanto no final é boa prática colocar um "else", mesmo que não faça nada, desta forma:

```
elif media < 3.9:
    print (n,", sua média em Biologia foi",media,"Você esta reprovado")
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, acredito que o erro esteja na forma com que esta usando o else, veja o que estamos fazendo!

- Se media maior 6 : faça isso;
- Se não for maior que 6 e maior que 4 : faça isso;
- Se não media menor que 3 : .... (aqui até para leitura ficou ruim);

O else sem if não pode testar mais condições! Adicione mais um elif ali:

```
if media >= 6:
   print (n,", sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você foi aprovado")
elif media <= 5.9 and media >= 4: 
   print (n,",sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você esta de recuperação")
elif media < 3.9:
   print (n,", sua média em Biologia foi",media,"Você esta reprovado")
```

Aqui se quiser utilizar o else para dar outro print

```
if media >= 6:
   print (n,", sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você foi aprovado")
elif media <= 5.9 and media >= 4: 
   print (n,",sua média em Biologia é,",media,"você esta de recuperação")
elif media < 3.9 and >= 0:
   print (n,", sua média em Biologia foi",media,"Você esta reprovado")
else: #Observe que o else aqui não vai testar condições!
   print (n,"......")
```