# Format & End em impressão no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Estou criando uma aplicação que faz conexão com o db **Sqlite**, pesquisa e retorna a coluna da tabela em questão, o problema é que o resultado retornado sem formatação vem assim : `( u'Field 1, Field 2' )`, para imprimir eu tentei usar um `for` dentro de `for` e imprimindo cada campo com um `print ( '{0} {1} ... '.format ( ... ) ) ,` e um `end = '\n'` ao final para ficar bem formatado, porém o Pyhton não aceita e preciso que isso seja bem dinâmico pois o número de itens pode variar a cada db criado ( O usuário escolhe os campos e os tipos ), pesquisei um pouco mas não encontrei uma boa forma para imprimir esses dados, ficaria grato se puderem enviar referências ou explicações.

`print ( '{0} {1} ... '.format ( ... ), end = '\n' )`

Comment: Seria [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82733/como-concatenar-multiplas-strings-em-python) que vc precisa.

Comment: Não, pois nesse exemplo que tu enviou ele especifica quantos itens vão ser impressos : `'Nome : {} Idade : {} Cpf : {}'.format ( campo [1], campo [2], campo [3] )` e no meu caso eu não tenho como saber quantos campos o usuário adicionou, logo se eu colocar ' estático ' dessa forma a aplicação quebra em outro db que tenha mais campos.

Comment: Vc precisa concatenar a string dinamicamente?

Comment: Me de um exemplo de entrada dos dados, e a saída que vc deseja?

Comment: Entrada : `( 'Table-Name', ( 'Name text', 'Age integer' ... n ) )`, saida : `Darth Vader 300 ...`, sim, concatenar ela dinamicamente.

Comment: Então vc só irá exibir os valores?

Comment: Isso que vc chama de "entrada", é o retorno da função que lê a tabela? É uma tupla de tuplas? tá meio confuso, seria interessante se voce colocasse o codigo dessa funcao.

Comment: Só vou exibir, não estou no notbook que o código está neste momento, essa ' entrada ' são o argumentos que tenho que passar para a tabela ( Informação sendo adicionada na tabela ), a saida são os valores que são obtidos por um select no `cursor`, resumindo ... não se importem com o Db, apenas em imprimir, só preciso imprimir isso aqui `( u ' Bla, Bla, Bla ' )` desta forma : `Bla Bla Bla`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptei este código com base [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865933/5429980) do SOen.

Se sua entrada de dados, for os valores das colunas que foram selecionadas numa query. É possível formatar a saída independente da quantidade de colunas especificada:

```
valores = ["gato", "gato@mail.com", "26", "Vila dos gatos"]

print(' '.join('{}'.format(c) for i, c in enumerate(valores, 1)))
```

Saída:

> gato gato@mail.com 26 Rua dos gatos

Neste exemplo ele usa o `join` e a função `enumerate` para formatar os dados.

## Edição

Um ajuste sugerido pelo o [jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/500/jsbueno) para melhorar e otimizar a rotina:

```
print(' '.join(str(valor) for valor in valores))
```

Saída

> gato gato@mail.com 26 Rua dos gatos

Comentário do jsbueno:

> Perceba que você não precisa do enumerate aí: ele vai criar um número
>   correspondente a cada item, mas você está formatando uma string de
>   cada vez - então com um único parâmetro. (Se fosse usar o número seria
>   só colocar "{0}" na string dentro do join). Veja que você nem mesmo
>   usa a variável "i" que é onde vai o valor do enumerate. O melhor aí é
>   simplesmente: `print(' '.join(str(valor) for valor in valores))` (já
>   que não vai nada além do valor na string, "str" é mais curto do que
>   chamar o método de "format")

Comment: Perceba que você não precisa do enumerate aí: ele vai criar um número correspondente a cada item, mas você está formatando uma string de cada vez - então com um único parâmetro.  (Se fosse usar o número seria só colocar "{0}"  na string dentro do join).  Veja que você nem mesmo usa a variável "i" que é onde vai o valor do enumerate.

O melhor aí é simplesmente: `print(' '.join(str(valor) for valor in valores))`  (já que não vai nada além do valor na string, "str" é mais curto do que chamar o método de "format")

Comment: @jsbueno editado ;)